# Calling npx using python script

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, npm, npx

I'd like to run an  **npx command line tool** using a python script,
Something like:
`subprocess.Popen("npx chatito trainClimateBot.chatito",shell=True).wait()` 
but this does not work and throws the following error:,

```
 ==== CHATITO SYNTAX ERROR ====
     Expected "#", "%", "//", "@[", "import ", "~", or end of line  but end of input found.
     Line: 1, Column: 1
==============================
FULL ERROR REPORT:
{ SyntaxError: Expected "#", "%", "//", "@[", "import ", "~", or end of line  but end of input found.
at peg$buildStructuredError (.\.\.\npm-cache\_npx\10168\node_modules\chatito\parser\chatito.js:381:12)
at Object.peg$parse [as parse] ((.\.\.\npm-cache\_npx\10168\node_modules\chatito\parser\chatito.js:3563:11)
```

So, is there a way to run an npx command via python script?

Comment: Is it normal that you don't start with `npx` in your command line ?

Comment: Missed that out.Question is edited :)

Comment: Try `subprocess.run(["npx", "chatito", "trainClimateBot.chatito"], capture_output=True)`.